# linux rename and move files with specific extention in other folder and do command with each file - ocrmypdf

Tags: linux, bash, automation, copy, rename

currently i'm learning linux and want to use **ocrmypdf** with an **automatisation** for scans.

For this i got three folders:

- Input - for scans to be processed by ocrmypdf
- Output - pdfs with ocr after processing
- RAW - copy of the scan without ocr

My goal is to **watch** the "Input" folder and when a *.pdf* comes in this *Input* folder, it will be processed:

1. First only look for "***.pdf**" files in the *Input* folder to avoid errors by ocrmypdf later
2. Copy each pdf in the **RAW folder** for backup before processing with ocrmypdf
3. rename it with "filenamexyz**_RAW**.pdf"
4. **ocrmypdf** (a commandline "expression") for the pdfs like `ocrmypdf -l deu+eng input.pdf output.pdf` or maybe then `ocrmypdf -l deu+eng input.pdf input.pdf` to overwrite the pdf because it's already saved in the raw folder before
5. Put this pdf with ocr in the *Output* folder

I already found **watchdog** to recognize changes in the folder and this could trigger this automatisation - maybe it could also be a **script with an cronjob every 30 secounds** in this folder.

Would be very happy if someone of the pro's could give me a hint or a short script :)

...still learning -  Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: I think you might be looking for something like `find /path/to/Input/ -name '*.pdf' -exec cp {} /path/to/RAW/ \; -exec ocrmypdf ... \;`  I don't know the syntax for ocrmypdf, but you can fill in the rest.  Just use `{}` in place of where you would put the file name.  Oh, and I would use cron over watchdog here.  I'm not sure if could apply watchdog to this.

Comment: Hey Jason, thank you very much for your idea. Your code would be a one-liner right? And yes i think this would be good line for a crobjob to run it like every 15 minutes. That should be often enough and i don't need to wait that long. Because on the other hand 99% of the time there are no file to process. (I'm not scanning every minute)

Try to get things clear:

`find /path/to/Input/ -name '*.pdf' -exec cp {} /path/to/RAW/ \; -exec ocrmypdf -l deu+eng input.pdf output.pdf \;`

This would find all PDFs in my Input folder, then copy it to the RAW folder. Does it rename it with "xyz_RAW"?

Comment: The copy of each file in the Raw folder should be renamed with `filenamexyz_RAW`. filenamexyz must be unique like given in the input folder. So it's basically an addition "_RAW" to each filename. I guess there must be a expression in the place of `{}` to use the right filename. I found this `filename="${filename%.*}"` but run into problems to implement it.